# Vue2 modal in v-for list

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement a vue2 `modal` as described in the vue docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html.

It looks something like this:

```
<tbody v-if="fields.length">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in fields">
        <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="item.active"></td>
        <td>
            <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <modal :item="item" v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
        <h3 slot="header">Hello World</h3>
    </modal>
</tbody>


Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    data: function() {
        return {
            item: ''
        }
    }
});
```

While the button shows up and does pop up the modal, I get a warning that `Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.`, and when I inspect the `modal` component in the Vue dev tools, the `item` is still `''`, it's not populated by the `:item` binding.

What's the right way to pass the `item` object into the modal so we can use it in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing `item` as a value from the parent to a child component, you cannot use `data`--you must use `props` instead!

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    props: ['item'],
    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things:

1. You don't reference item in the data object instead you should reference it as a prop for the component `props: ['item']`.
2. The modal is not inside the loop's scope, which ends at the closing `</tr>` tag. You could change this so that the click action performs a method that takes the item and assigns it to a variable that is always passed in like a prop. This would be similar to how you are doing it now, you would just change `showModal = true` to `openModal(item)` then have a method that would set the appropriate 2 values. Something like this:

   ```
   openModal(item) {
     this.showModal = true;
     this.modalItem = item;
   }

   ...

   data: () => {
     modalItem: null
     ...
   }
   ```